# Menu not branching out in Kentico 7

Tags: drop-down-menu, tree, kentico

There are two different websites with drop-down menus, but only one is having the appropriate "branch-out" affect.

Picture 1 is the one not branching and picture 2 is doing what I want:

[No Branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUBJF.png)

[Branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRRQ9.png)

The menu that is correct is using a tree menu widget and the other is not, only a breadcrumbs widget.  As you can see I added a "Test Page" under Government, but it is simply at the bottom of the menu.  If it's just a matter of inserting a Tree Menu widget to get the affect I want, I'll do that, but I wanted to see if there was another solution first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be an issue with the webpart used for the menu.  So the one site showing correctly may have the levels set to the necessary depth whereas the other site may not.  This doesn't seem to be the case though as the webpart is picking up the "Test Page" but not the "Tax Matters" page.

It could also be an issue with the overall design of the site's menu.  Maybe the site's menu wasn't designed with 3 levels of depth on it.  To check this you can go to the webparts transformation property and see if there are multiple levels setup to display that 2nd and 3rd level nested within one another.

Not knowing the configuration of your webpart or the transformation makes it a bit harder to actually troubleshoot.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having trouble even locating the webparts transformation property.